# SecItemCopyMatching memory leaking

Tags: iphone, security, rsa

I have a memory leak in the next code. I inspired from [here](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-lib/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsecurity) and this is a part of RSA algorithm.

```
- (SecKeyRef)getPublicKeyRef {
OSStatus resultCode = noErr;
SecKeyRef publicKeyReference = NULL;

if(publicKey == NULL) {
    NSMutableDictionary * queryPublicKey = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    NSData *publicTag = [NSData dataWithBytes:publicKeyIdentifier

                                       length:strlen((const char *)publicKeyIdentifier)]; 

    // Set the public key query dictionary.
    [queryPublicKey setObject:(id)kSecClassKey forKey:(id)kSecClass];
    [queryPublicKey setObject:publicTag forKey:(id)kSecAttrApplicationTag];

    [queryPublicKey setObject:(id)kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA forKey:(id)kSecAttrKeyType];

    [queryPublicKey setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(id)kSecReturnRef];

    // Get the key.     
    resultCode = SecItemCopyMatching((CFDictionaryRef)queryPublicKey, (CFTypeRef *)&publicKeyReference);
   // NSLog(@"getPublicKey: result code: %d", resultCode);

    if(resultCode != noErr)
    {
        publicKeyReference = NULL;
    }

    // [publicTag release];
    [queryPublicKey release];
} else {
    publicKeyReference = publicKey;
}

return publicKeyReference;
```

}

The Leak instrument says it is leaking in this line:

```
resultCode = SecItemCopyMatching((CFDictionaryRef)queryPublicKey, (CFTypeRef *)&publicKeyReference);
```

Please tell me how could I solve this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your method is *sometimes* returning an instance with retain count +1 and you are most likely not releasing it in the rest of your code. You are returning with retain count +1 if SecItemCopyMatching is called, but if publicKey is set then your function is returning a value with retain count +-0 which is bad.

You need to make sure that you always return with the same retain count. In this case, I'd do:

```
} else {
    publicKeyReference = publicKey;
    CFRetain(publicKeyReference);
}
```

Then every caller to your method must make sure to `CFRelease` the value... but that'd violate the *get* rule (it should return retain count +-0), so maybe it would be a good idea to then rename the method.

Comment: But what about SecItemCopyMatching, Leak instrument says this is the place where the leak occurs.

Comment: Yes, because you are not `CFRelease` ing the value that gets returned by `getPublicKeyRef` in your code uses `getPublicKeyRef`. And Instruments tells you where it was allocated. Therefor, you must `CFRelease` that value somewhere. But then it would crash if `publicKey` is already set, which is why you must retain it as well so that your method always returns a value with a retain count of +1.

Comment: Look this is the only place from where it is called, isn't it released there?   status = SecKeyEncrypt([self getPublicKeyRef],
                           PADDING,
                           plainBuffer,
                           size,
                           &cipherBuffer[0],
                           &cipherBufferSize
                           );

Comment: Had the same issue, strange that the docs do not specifically mention that the returned CFDictionaryRef will have a retain count of +1. Anyway, in code similar to yours, I just call `[publicKeyReference autorelease]` if the return status was `noErr` and all is good. :)

Comment: DarkDust could you please have a look at my similar issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39873319/cfrelease-crash-in-ios10