# CFRelease crash in iOS10

Tags: objective-c, ios10, xcode8, core-foundation, seckeyref

Below is my code, which used to work fine till iOS 9.

```
- (NSData *)encryptWithDataPublicKey:(NSString*)data keyTag:(NSString*)tag
{  

    SecKeyRef publicKey = NULL;                                           
    NSData *publicTag = [NSData dataWithBytes:[tag UTF8String] length:[tag length]];

    NSMutableDictionary *queryPublicKey =
    [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [queryPublicKey setObject:(__bridge id)kSecClassKey forKey:(__bridge id)kSecClass];  

    [queryPublicKey setObject:publicTag forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrApplicationTag];

    [queryPublicKey setObject:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyType];

    [queryPublicKey setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(__bridge id)kSecReturnRef];

    OSStatus status = SecItemCopyMatching
    ((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)queryPublicKey, (CFTypeRef *)&publicKey);

    NSData *encodedData = nil;  

    if (status == noErr && publicKey) {  
        NSData *dataToEncrypt = [data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];  
        encodedData = [self encryptData:dataToEncrypt withKeyRef:publicKey];  
        CFRelease(publicKey);  
    }  
    return encodedData;  
}
```

This method used to work fine till iOS 9.x, But today when I have updated my XCode to 8 and run on iOS 10 device. Application is getting crashed at
***CFRelease(publicKey)***.

Before crashing below is the log from console.

> could not load any Objective-C class information. This will
>   significantly reduce the quality of type information available

[image]

Could not able to get the issue exactly.

When I enabled Zombie, and reproduce the crash. Below is the log from console.

*** -[Not A Type release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x170225880

Thanks in advance.

I got the Issue.
there is an inner method encodedData = [self encryptData:dataToEncrypt withKeyRef:publicKey];

where SecKeyRef object is getting released.

But I wonder how this worked till iOS9???????

```
-(NSData *)encryptData:(NSData *)data withKeyRef:(SecKeyRef) keyRef{
    const uint8_t *srcbuf = (const uint8_t *)[data bytes];
    size_t srclen = (size_t)data.length;

    size_t block_size = SecKeyGetBlockSize(keyRef) * sizeof(uint8_t);
    void *outbuf = malloc(block_size);
    size_t src_block_size = block_size - 11;

    NSMutableData *ret = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    for(int idx=0; idx<srclen; idx+=src_block_size){
        size_t data_len = srclen - idx;
        if(data_len > src_block_size){
            data_len = src_block_size;
        }

        size_t outlen = block_size;
        OSStatus status = noErr;
        status = SecKeyEncrypt(keyRef,
                               kSecPaddingPKCS1,
                               srcbuf + idx,
                               data_len,
                               outbuf,
                               &outlen
                               );
        if (status != 0) {
            ret = nil;
            break;
        }else{
            [ret appendBytes:outbuf length:outlen];
        }
    }

    free(outbuf);
    CFRelease(keyRef);
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: First, run the static analyzer and make sure that it's not returning any warnings. Does `encryptData:withKeyRef:` apply any memory management to `publicKey`? I agree that this crash is a bit surprising.

Comment: I did run the static analyzer, there is no warning. But couldn't able to resolve the crash issue. clue less

Comment: why do you want to _release_ an object which you did not _own_?

Comment: holex .. it worked fine till iOS9. crashing since iOS10 update.

Comment: @holex, because `SecItemCopyMatching` includes `Copy`. It must be balanced with a release.

Comment: @RobNapier, that is true but OP does not _own_ the `publicKey` – as the edited post clarifies the my initial suspicion undoubtably.

Comment: @holex I don't understand your meaning here. The call to `SecItemCopyMatching` makes the caller an owner of `publicKey`. The caller must balance that call with a `CFRelease`, and correctly does. (Or am I missing your meaning here?) The edited code includes an incorrect release of `keyRef`, which that method does not own (since it did not call `Create`, `Copy`, or `Retain` on it), and that extraneous release must be removed, but not the one that references `publicKey` (yes, `publicKey` and `keyRef` are the same object ultimately, but that's not relevant here).

Comment: @RobNapier, what I was saying is that _at that particular point_ when OP invokes the `CFRelease(publicKey)` (which crashes), he has __already__ lost his _ownership_ of the `publicKey` (that is why the app crashed). that must have happened somewhere between calling `SecItemCopyMatching` and `CFRelease(publicKey)`, and according to his code it seems the OP __already__ released that object inside the `-encryptData:...`. I'm not saying any mysterious thing here, I've pointed out precisely that he tries to release an object which did not own, but I didn't see the rest of the code when I commented.

Comment: @holex I believe this is an unhelpful way to think of memory management and leads to dangerous practices. `encryptWithDataPublicKey` took ownership by calling `Copy`. It did not give it up or otherwise lose it. It can only do that by calling `Release`. The fact that some other piece of code (`encryptData`) released an object it did not own has no bearing on `encryptWithDataPublicKey`'s ownership. CF memory management should always be considered locally (within a lexical scope) and only in terms of the rules.

Comment: I only push this point because when devs think in the way you're describing, they often come to the conclusion that they should remove the `CFRelease(publicKey)` call in `encryptWithDataPublicKey` because "they've given up ownership elsewhere." This would be a completely incorrect solution to the above problem. `encryptWithDataPublicKey` is correct and should not be changed, no matter what other parts of the code are doing. Those other, incorrect parts, need to be fixed.

Comment: @RobNapier, the OP __did not own__ the object when he wanted to release it; they __had__ ownership when the `SecItemCopyMatching` method invoked and they __lost__ the ownership by when tried to invoke `CFRelease(publicKey)`; that happened here, and that is what I commented – I didn't intend to justify or clarifying _how_, _why_ or _when_ they lost it and _what_ would be the proper way to manage it... someone who wants to get the credit for answering the question should investigate the circumstances. no need to antagonise me just because I have spotted that accurately and stopped there.

Comment: Thank you @RobNapier & holex for the detailed analysis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `encryptData:withKeyRef:` you have an unbalanced `CFRelease` at the end of the method. Nothing in that method retained `keyRef`, but you release it. Remove that call.

Why didn't it crash before? Because something else was likely retaining it internally previously, possibly a cache, possibly something else. Cocoa makes no promises that an over-release will immediately (or ever) lead to a crash. You were into undefined behavior.

It's very distressing, though, that the static analyzer isn't detecting this. I would open a bug report about that (bugreport.apple.com). You have a very clear memory management violation and the analyzer should have caught it.